# Unable to connect Windows 10 server using Remmina on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04, remote-desktop, rdp, remmina

I am not able to connect to a Windows VM from Ubuntu's Remmina. It was all working fine till the day before yesterday but when I tried yesterday- the issue emerged. I asked my colleagues to try connect to Win server from their systems, surprisingly only Windows users are able to connect but none of Ubuntu users.
 
I have found similar posts on SE, but they could not helped me.

[1]. [remmina no longer working "cannot connect to RDP server localhost"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193364/remmina-no-longer-working-cannot-connect-to-rdp-server-localhost)

[2]. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/445613/cant-connect-to-remote-server-using-rdp-remmina-after-upgrade

[3]. [Remmina on Ubuntu 20.04 is unable to RDP to Windows 10 Server](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284786/remmina-on-ubuntu-20-04-is-unable-to-rdp-to-windows-10-server)

This is what I have tried

(1). [2] suggests  "*updating all freerdp2 libraries (used by remmina) to 2.0.0~git20181120.1 version*", but I do not know exactly which ones? I have `sudo apt install freerdp2-dev`

(2). Removed the  `~/.config/freerdp/known_hosts2` file

(3). [3] suggested `sudo ip link delete docker0`, upon trying I received `Cannot find device "docker0"`

Any suggestions?